# Get string inside NSDictionary in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, twitter

I have made a struct that is helping me fetching info from a twitter json. The json has values such as text, which I am able to fetch without a problem, but it also has a dictionary names `user` and it has the string screen_name inside it.

How can I access that string?

Here is how I access the `text` string and how I fetch the user dictionary:

```
func parseTwitterJSON(_ data:Data) {

    var jsonResult = NSArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    let twitterLocations = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count{
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
        let twitterLocation = twitterLocationModel()
        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let lang = jsonElement["lang"] as? String,
            let text = jsonElement["text"] as? String,
            let user = jsonElement["user"] as? NSDictionary
        {

            twitterLocation.lang = lang
            twitterLocation.text = text
            twitterLocation.user = user    
        }

        twitterLocations.add(twitterLocation)   
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        self.delegate.twitterDownloaded(items: twitterLocations)
    })
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift? Use the native Swift types, `Array` and `Dictionary` unless you have a very good reason to use their old Foundation alternatives.

Comment: I do not know a lot about swift yet, I am trying to learn. I thought I needed to use them. I am trying to display tweets in my tableviewcontroller, but I do not understand how to use the correct way via the Twitter SDK.

Comment: Use 'Codable' model objects and JSONDecoder to convert the data response to corresponding objects. You don't have to parse each value manually.

Comment: @ArunGJ do you have any example of that, a link to an example or something like that? I do not get a lot out of the Twitter Documentation.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999

Comment: As @ArunGJ points out, using `struct`s that conform to the `Codable` protocol is a lot easier for coding/decoding JSON. If your app's gonna be decoding JSON a lot, probably worth learning about Codable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the value of a key from a dictionary you would use

```
let myDictName : [String:String] = ["keyName" : "value"]
let value = myDictName["keyName"]
//value will be equal to "value"
```

Since you have the element user as an dictionary, you can just say

```
let userName = user["screen_name"]
```

Comment: The string isn't closed in the subscript

Comment: @paper1111 Fixed it. Thanks for telling me.